# Docker run --restart=always does not pick up updated docker image tag

Tags: docker

I am just curious if this behavior is expected or not.

When keeping a service always running with `--restart=always`, even if the image tag that you specified the `run` with has been updated, it will continue to restart the old tag.

Documentation is not clear on this.

Even forcibly removing the image does not result in the new tag getting picked up, it just seems to get shown as  in the list of images until all containers running it actually get stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the answer is that a container started with "always restart" has to be stopped in order to make it update.